# How to start a new http server or using an existing one for pprof?

Tags: http, go

The [pprof](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/) package documentation says

> The package is typically only imported for the side effect of registering its HTTP handlers. The handled paths all begin with /debug/pprof/."

The documentation says if you already have an http server running you don't need to start another one but if you are not using DefaultServeMux, you will have to register handlers with the mux you are using.

Shouldn't I always use a separate port for pprof? Is it okay to use the same port that I am using for prometheus metrics?

Comment: It's not okay if you expose that application. If you're doing it temporary for your local development and then will remove it from the release - it's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`net/http/pprof` is a convenience package. It always registers handlers on `DefaultServeMux`, because `DefaultServeMux` is a global variable that it can actually do that with.

If you want to serve pprof results on some other `ServeMux` there's really nothing to it; all it takes is calling `runtime/pprof.StartCPUProfile(w)` with an `http.ResponseWriter` and then sleeping, or calling `p.WriteTo(w, debug)` on a `runtime/pprof.Profile` object. You can look at the [source of net/http/pprof](https://golang.org/src/net/http/pprof/pprof.go) to see how it does it.

In a slightly better universe, `net/http/pprof` would have a `RegisterHandlers(*http.ServeMux)` function that could be used anywhere, you would be able to import it without anything being registered implicitly, and there would be *another* package (say `net/http/pprof/sugar`) that did nothing except call `pprof.RegisterHandlers(http.DefaultServeMux)` in its `init`. However, we don't live in that universe.